# Error when running 'Install-Module': is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell

Running a machine with windows 10, and using powershell 5

```
PS C:\Users\Amir> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  0
```

When trying to import a module I get an error.

When searching on this, the only solution provided is to upgrade to powershell 5,
but I am already running it.

```
Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI
```

> Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

**Edit:**
after further debugging the issue was traced to failed windows update service.
after correcting additional issues with failing windows update service, powershell is now updated to version 5.1.16299.98 and Install-Module is working as expected.
since the issue is not reproducible, this can be considered as resolved.

Thanks.

Comment: If you run `get-module -name PowerShellGet` do you have anything?

Comment: running `get-module -name PowerShellGet` produces no output.

Comment: See @Theincorigible1's answer. If that works you're set, but if not it sounds like somehow you're missing the module that comes with powershell 5. Getting PowerShellGet from another machine could be a fix in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a corrupted PATH environment variable.  This can be confirmed by running this command:

```
$Env:PSModulePath -split ';' | Sort-Object
```

and looking for the below command's path in the list.

---

The following should resolve your problem:

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet' -Verbose
Get-Command -Name 'Install-Module'
```

---

And a permanent fix:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
    'PSModulePath',
    [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', 'Machine') +
        ';C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules',
    'Machine'
)
```